# Checking if file exists before removing it in makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a makefile within a C++ project (compiler: C++11).  How can you check to see if a particular file exists before removing it with a makefile command?
Here is the code:

```
bin: charstack.h error.h
        g++ -Wall -std=c++11 main.cpp charstack.cpp error.cpp -o bin

run:
        ./bin.exe

clean:
        rm bin.exe

# This statement removes auto generated backups on my system.
cl:
        rm charstack.h~ charstack.cpp~ main.cpp~ makefile~ error.h~ error.cpp~
```

How would I have the makefile check to see whether the auto generated .~ backup files exist before attempting to remove them when the user passes

```
make cl
```

in the command line?  The goal here is to avoid outputting these errors to the terminal upon running "make cl":

```
rm: cannot remove `charstack.h~': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove `charstack.cpp~': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove `main.cpp~': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove `error.h~': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove `error.cpp~': No such file or directory
make: *** [cl] Error 1
```

Comment: The title was better before. Now it's (a) non-descript, and (b) names the wrong technology.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Honestly, that's an *XY problem*, it is not due neither to the fact that the project is a C++ one nor that it uses the spec C++11.

Because of that, the title of the question is a bit misleading, as well as its tags.

Anyway, you can use the option `-f`. From the man page of `rm`:

> ignore nonexistent files and arguments, never prompt

So, it's enough to use the following line:

```
 rm -f charstack.h~ charstack.cpp~ main.cpp~ makefile~ error.h~ error.cpp~
```

Actually, it doesn't check if those files exist, but also it doesn't complain if they don't exist.

Comment: This is indeed the canonical approach.

Comment: Easy fix.  Thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome. Do not forget to accept a response if it solves your problem, it will help newcomers and future searches.

Comment: Do you have any idea if Windows 8.0 Powershell supports anything similar to a man function?

Comment: Unfortunately no, but I suggest you to search throughout SO and eventually open a new question. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Even though this question has been answered, I attach a different solution that works for both files *AND* directories (because `rm -rf DIRNAME` is not silent anymore)

Here is a rule for removing a directory in variable `${OUTDIR}` only if the directory exists. The example is easily adjusted for files:

```
clean:
    if [ -d "${OUTDIR}" ]; then \
        rm -r ${OUTDIR}; \
    fi \
```

Note that the key observation is that you have to write the usual bash if-then-esle as if it where on a single line (i.e. using `\` before a newline, and with a `;` after each command). The example can be easily adapted to different (non-bash) shells.